# Lookup field with multiple locations for SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, custom-field-type

Folks!

In my recent project I’ve faced with the situation when I need to develop “tricky” Custom Field Type (CFT) for Share Point 2010. That CFT must behave like an Out-Of-The-Box Lookup Field, but it must point to couple of different locations. For example, the Lookup field can be pointed to the web A, list B in the web A and to the some field in the list B – let’s call that like a Location, but my field must be able to point to many Locations at the same time. In addition to that main requirement, my CFT must be sortable, filterable and represent an ability to search by EQUAL using CAML, like a Lookup field. Does anybody faced with such tasks? SharePoint masters, please, instruct me with the RIGHT path!!!

Comment: Does it need to be a CFT? This sounds like something Managed Meta Data could store.